# Find the average value of f(x)=-1/(x^3) on [1/2,2].

Tags: calculus

How do you use the average value theorem to evaluate this? Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: $$\dfrac{1}{2-1/2}\int_{1/2}^2 \dfrac{-1}{x^3} dx$$

Comment: The average value of a function $ \ f(x) \ $ on an interval $ \ [a, b] \ $ is taken to be the height of a rectangle with a base of $ \ (b - a) \ $ so that the area of that rectangle is the same as the area "under the curve" for $ \ f(x) \ $ on the same interval.  In this case, the curve is _below_ the $ \ x-$ axis, so the average value will be negative.

Comment: Is the answer -7/12?

Comment: You can check your integral results with a graphing calculator or wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282-%281%2F2%29%29+*Integrate%5B-1%2Fx%5E3%2C%7Bx%2C1%2F2%2C2%7D%5D

Comment: It's not giving me an answer...

Comment: @rororo   On your integration, be careful: what is the anti-derivative of $ \ -x^{-3} \ $ ? (The average is not $ \ -\frac{7}{12} \ $ .)

Comment: The + between the 9 and *Integrate should be removed from the URL. Alternatively, you can enter it into your own calculator or something to check the answer. And at least try your homework before posting it on Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value of $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is $\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$.

Plug in $a=\frac{1}{2}$, $b=2$, $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^3}$, carry out the integral, done.